# Date time error in VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

My below code is doing kind of duration calculation, but at run time it is throwing an exception that `type mismatch`, although both of the parameter has `date values` within them.So any suggestion where the bug is?

**Code:**

```
Function TimeSpan(dt1,dt2)
Dim dtTemp

objExcel1.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If (IsDate(dt1) And IsDate(dt2)) = False Then
        TimeSpan = "00:00:00"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If dt2 < dt1 Then
        dtTemp = dt2
        dt2 = dt1
        dt1 = dt2
    End If
    '-- since you only had days, I have put up to days here. 
    '-- if you require months, years you may use yy:mm:dd:hh:mm:ss
    '-- which is pretty self-explainatory ;)
    Msgbox("DT2:" & dt2 & "DT1:" & dt1)
    TimeSpan = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Text((dt2 - dt1), "[h]:mm:ss")'"dd:hh:mm:ss"

objExcel1.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

[image: Date values to the parameters passed by the Calle]

[image: Date error]

**@Tomalak** I have updated the code as per you and now getting below error.

**CODE**

```
Function TimeSpan(dt1, dt2)
    If Not (IsDate(dt1) And IsDate(dt2)) Then

        TimeSpan = "00:00:00"

    ElseIf dt2 < dt1 Then

        TimeSpan = TimeSpan(dt2, dt1)

    Else

        MsgBox((CDate(dt1) - CDate(dt2)))
        TimeSpan = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Text( (CDate(dt1) - CDate(dt2)), "[h]:mm:ss" )

    End If  

End Function
```

`Msgbox Displaying:`

[image]

[image: New Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function `DateDiff()` available, which makes life simpler:

```
 Function TimeSpan(dt1, dt2)

    If Not (IsDate(dt1) And IsDate(dt2)) Then
        TimeSpan = "00:00:00"
    Else
       TimeSpan = Abs(DateDiff("s", dt2, dt1)) / 3600
         TimeSpan = TimeSpan / 24
    End If

 MsgBox (TimeSpan)
```

The result is in days, re-calculated from seconds to achieve the needed (minutes and seconds) accuracy and compatibility with date formats.

Comment: Can I get the result in :"[h]:mm:ss" format, as i need to store it finally to the Excel cell?

Comment: in the `else` part why you called the function `twice`?

Comment: I wanted to be able to comment out the second row and have hours with one finger movement, while trying to play with formats.

Comment: If you write the TimeSpan result into range `A2` (or somewhere else), add one line: `Range("A2").NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but your values might be string values.  IsDate() will return true if the value is a string that can be converted to a date.  But, in that case, the subtraction will fail.  You can fix that with the CDate() or CVDate() function:

```
TimeSpan = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Text((CDate(dt2) - CDate(dt1)), "[h]:mm:ss")'"dd:hh:mm:ss"
```

To work around the "unable to get..." error, try this:

```
Dim bSign
bSign = CDate(dt2) < CDate(dt1)
TimeSpan = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Abs(CDate(dt2) - CDate(dt1)), "[h]:mm:ss")'"dd:hh:mm:ss"
If bSign Then
    TimeSpan = "-" & TimeSpan
End If
```

Comment: in which case the subtraction will be failed,you doubt. Please explain me. It is not clear to me.Just giving you a background about the algorithm i used in my VBScript. There is an excel sheet and I have loaded the rows into the `ArrayList` object, to do some manipulations and after that through loop i called the above function to pass the times and calculate the durations and return it back to the ArrayIndex.

Comment: @VBSlover what values are in the sheet?  Try calling your function like `TimeSpan("1/1/2012", "1/1/2013")` to test my hypothesis.

Comment: the date values are `09/01/2012 01:11:11 PM`,`09/01/2012 01:18:05 PM`, so on in the `ArrayList` object!

Comment: @VBSlover yes, but are they strings or actual date-type values?  What happens if you add `MsgBox TypeName(dt1)`?

Comment: `MsgBox TypeName(dt1)` giving as `String`!

Comment: @VBSlover what did I tell you ... use CDate to coerce the value to a Date type.  You cannot subtract strings!  The error raised when you try to subtract strings is, not surprisingly, type mismatch.

Comment: @VBSlover sorry, KimI was offline when you left that last comment. Have you resolved that error yet?

Comment: @VBSlover that "unable to get..." error appears to be a result of the fact that the value you're formatting is negative.  I edited the answer with one possible workaround.

Comment: we can't assume that dt2 always would be greater than the dt1, reverse can be happened,then how to handel the same.Please advice!

Comment: @VBSlover I forgot to add an `Abs` call in my recent edit; I've corrected that.

Comment: may I have some help on the post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085891/excel-dashboard-creation

Comment: @VBSlover you're converting a value to a string using a method that can't handle negative values.  The workaround: determine whether the value is negative, convert its absolute value, and, if the value is negative, prepend a minus sign.  The `bSign` variable is a flag that stores whether the original value was negative.  I'll have a look at your new post now.

Comment: can you help me in my above post?